# Where is the safest place to put servers

Tags: webserver, dmz

Currently, I have modem with built-in NAT and DMZ. I have 250Mb of webspace and unlimited emails supplied by my ISP on WAN. I want to move the webspace to my own PC on a LAN along with the emails so I can change ISP to a faster fibre. BUT Security is the issue!

I want to know where to add a PC to supply webspace to be accessible by the world but not hackable into my network. Where does a web server go to allow use of a web server for web pages but not allow access to a private network on the same IP address (domain) but also allow the PC to download all my emails and be a server to the LAN so users on the LAN can access their emails without being hacked from outside the LAN or on the WAN?

Do I have to use a separate PC so the connection goes

```
WAN-webPC, WAN-DMZ, WAN-NAT-emailPC, WAN-NAT-LAN
```

or can webPC and emailPC be the same? with software NAT? which is the securest setup for WAN, webPC, email, PC and LAN that blocks hackers but allows users to see a web page only, and LAN users to access the WAN without being visible to WAN hackers?

Comment: Rather than worrying about how to keep you web server safe from the rest of your network, you should consider how to keep the rest of your network safe from your web server.  Your web server is going to have 2 dedicated and well known ports open to the public at all times.   The answer to THAT is still opinion based/off topic, though, and forming an _informed_ opinion means saying more about your network than you should on a public forum like this.

Comment: So, you can break this down very simply: you want to prevent someone with access to the webserver from accessing your internal LAN. That's a DMZ, like you have already mentioned. What is on the server doesn't matter in terms of protecting your LAN. So, the question of whether you should have 2 different machines for web and email doesn't matter to what you are concerned about. So, the answer is simple: a DMZ with the web server and the email server. But it appears that you have other concerns, since that answer doesn't satisfy. What is your concern?

Comment: This is the purpose of DMZ - DMZ is "outside" the firewall. Computers in the DMZ can't access the LAN without going through some kind of firewall, and vice versa. As usual, don't forget to check the user manual for the modem/firewall in question because the little details may be different between different ones. Some of them might not let the LAN connect to the DMZ and that's a problem for you. You might need a feature called "hairpin NAT".

Comment: I would argue that this is less about security and more about configuring services. The security part is to some extent opiniated.

Comment: If I am understanding this the DMZ will allow users to access the Web server that NAT refuses. But an email server only requests out so can work behind a NAT?